# How to remove two-component adhesive from a stainless steel surface?

Tags: cleaning, adhesive, steel

My dad used a two-component adhesive when trying to glue a door stopper to our stainless steel radiator. However he read the manual wrong and now there is dried out glue on the radiator and the door stopper.

While mechanical removal of the glue from the stopper is no problem, as the side wont be visible after attaching it to the radiator, I see problems scratching the glue off the radiator itself as any visible scratches would look unpleasant.

Are there any other ways to remove the glue from a steel surface without damaging the steel itself?

Comment: Was the two-component adhesive an epoxy?

Comment: The resin is [methyl methacrylate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methyl_methacrylate) the hardener is [benzoyl peroxide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzoyl_peroxide). (so I guess it isn't an epoxy) The specific brand is Pattex Stabilit Express (I can't find any english information on it).

Comment: If the glue is hard like epoxy, you'll only have to rough up the surface slightly to reattach something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Heat gun - use a blow dryer or heat gun to soften the solution up.
2) Acetone - apply acetone to the spot. This will not penetrate the metal on the radiator.
3) Scrape - You can use an old t-shirt, stick the metal scraper inside the t-shirt and start chipping/smoothing away at the spot.

Repeat until it gets almost level with the radiator. You probably won't get it all up after the first pass.

After you do it again, you could get some medium grit sandpaper and try to smooth it away. Spot may still be there but raised surface shouldnt be nearly as bad.

Comment: Thanks, my dad already called the company and their chemist also suggested to use a heat gun. After applying heat (the glue turned golden-brown, like grilled cheese) it was easy to remove with a scraper without risking scratches.